# How to get CellTower-ID from GeoCoordinateWatcher

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have used this :

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
```

Where Hgh means GPS and Default is the result from any of these : GPS, WiFi

I like to know :

1) Is Default refering to CellTower ID or WIFI ? any different?

2) When I turn on my App running this Watcher inside the building ( not close to any entrance or window) , I can not get any result or no Signal at all from this watcher ?

If default refer to Wifi, it should be able to get the Cell_Tower ID .

If I am closer to the window or entrance of the building, I can get the result from Watcher.

Any1 can help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GeoPositionAccuracy does not directly refer to use of GPS or not.

The GeoPositionWatcher provides an abstraction layer to the way that the location is resolved internally. You will never know what was used to determine the location. Because the watcher does not indicate how the location was determined, it does not provide access to information based on a specific technology which may or may not have been used in identifying the device's location.

In theory, depending on the location of the device it may be possible to get a "High" accuracy reading based purely on public wifi data.

You cannot get the cell tower ID from any of the available APIs.

Comment: Thank for your info. Understand what you said about How it get the GPS data.  Now, I dont undertand, If I use WinMO 6.x I can get CellTowerID INSIDE a building, Why I can not get Whatever Gps Data they process and return in the same Spot inside the Building where I use WinMo 6.x? No GPS is ok, but What about the Gps data from CellTower, Wifi or any representation for this case?

Comment: @MilkBottle Window Mobile is a completely different product to Windows Phone 7. It's internals are different and it exposes a much larger collection of APIs. There is no way to get the Cell Tower ID through any of the public APIs on WP7 If your WP7 device is not able to connect to a cell network within a building but a different device, in the same physical position, can connect this is likely an issue with the constrution methods used and the position of the internal aerial.

Comment: Thanks. To make case clearer. Now, Both WP7 and WinMo6.x have Telco signal. Both are used inside a Building; Wp7 uses GeoCoordinateWatcher, WinMo use RIL. Since WP7 has signal strenght but can not get relevant GPS data in any form GPS, Wifi,CellID. To my understanding, as long as it has signal, it can get relevant GPS. Am I right ?

Comment: @MilkBottle if you have a cell signal and are asking for default accuracy you SHOULD be able to get some location information. Depending on the location this may not be the case as the cell tower information may not be enough for the WP7 location layer to get enough accuracy - you must check the status of the watcher to get an informed response.   Please note that GPS is different from cell network information.

Comment: Your statement is correct. After many tries, I came to understand your statement. Signal strenght plays a part in how to get the LatLon of your current postion as well as the database of country code and network code. Thank you.